# Ordered field with a maximum value

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

Is there any ordered field S with a maximum value?
i.e.,exist $n\in S$ such that $\forall x\in S$ \ {$n$},$x\le n$. What if '$\le$' is changed by '$\lt$'?

In the book **Elementary Analysis: The theory of Calculus (Kenneth A. Ross)**,Edition 2, P.24, it says:

> In other words,
>   there exists a mathematical system satisfying all the properties A1–
>   A4, M1–M4, DL and O1–O5 in §3 and yet possessing elements $a > 0$
>   and $b > 0$ such that $a < 1/n$ and $n < b$ for all $n$. <

As mentioned in comment by Henry, does hyperreal number or surreal number help? 

I wonder an example.

Thanks

Comment: Strictly *smaller than* hits the problem that $n \not \lt n$

Comment: Does the quote from Ross actually suggest an upper bound?  You might want to consider [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) and [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number)

Comment: @Henry ,I have just edited my post to avoid obivious n<n case. Hyperreal numbers and surreal numbers seems interesting, I will have a look at it. Thx